# Drop down horrizontal navi with jQuery

Tags: jquery, navigation, slidetoggle

I´ve got a special navigation and the structure may not be the best but i cant change it very much. This is a 3 level navigation.

For example:
You click on an level_1 nav item and the child level_2 and level_3 navigation appears.

### HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<nav class="mod_navigation block">
<ul class="level_1">
<li class="submenu sibling first selected">
<a class="submenu sibling first" href="#" title="">Lorem</a>
<ul class="level_2" style="display: block;">
<li class="submenu first">
<a class="submenu first" href="" title="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
<ul class="level_3">
<li class="first">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="submenu">
<li class="submenu last">
</ul>
</li>
<li class="submenu sibling">
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

But my js code only slides the content and not the background (css hover effect) item (.nav). Can you help me with my code?

### JS Code

```
var $topLevelItems = $("nav > ul > li");

    $topLevelItems.click(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $topLevelItems.removeClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2')
                .slideUp();

            $(this).addClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2')
                .slideDown();
        }
    });
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DvG6H/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the script; this will help you,

```
var $topLevelItems = $("nav > ul > li");


$('#nav').hover(function(){
    if($('.level_2:visible').length>0){
     $('.mod_navigation').animate({height:320},200);
    }
},function(){
    $('.mod_navigation').animate({height:50},200);
});

    $topLevelItems.click(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $topLevelItems.removeClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2')
                .slideUp();
             $('.mod_navigation').animate({height:320},200);
            $(this).addClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2')
                .slideDown();

        }
    });
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvG6H/5/)

Please try this one too,
This will handle the click function

```
var $topLevelItems = $("nav > ul > li");
    $topLevelItems.click(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $topLevelItems.removeClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2')
            .slideUp('slow');

            $(this).addClass('selected')
                .find('.level_2')
            .slideDown('slow',function(){
             $('.mod_navigation').animate({height:$topLevelItems.find('.level_2:visible').height()+55},200);
            });                       
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh im sorry, thats not what i meant, maybe i explained it to strange.
On click on the nav li, the height of ".nav" should scroll down as well.

Comment: Thats awesome but I've got one problem, when the cursour leaves the div ".nav" it slides up but it only should slide up when i klick on another nav item.

Comment: And the height of the subnav must be flexible.

Comment: @fr3d  : that is very simple, but once you clicked on any of the link it will always open

Comment: I know but how can i change the hover function into a toggle or click function like the other one?

Comment: Please see the second option in my answer

Comment: Cool, is there an attribut that saiyis, slide first completely up befor you slide down?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48874/discussion-between-nisam-and-fr3d)

Comment: How can i start the functions one after another and not at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

from #nav .level_2

```
#nav .level_2 {
display: none;
margin-top: 50px;
position: absolute;
}
```

edit the display to block:

as this:

```
#nav .level_2 {
display: block;
margin-top: 50px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: But the code changes the display value everytime the function starts.